# How do I read each line of uploaded file with mixed Windows and Unix line endings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-io

I am trying to read each line of an uploaded file in Rails.

```
file_data = params[:files]
    if file_data.respond_to?(:read)
      file_data.read.gsub( /\n/, "\r\n" ).split("\r\n").each do |line|
        inputUsers.push(line.strip)
      end
    elsif file_data.respond_to?(:path)
      File.read(file_data.path).gsub( /\n/, "\r\n" ).split("\r\n").each do |line|
       inputUsers.push(line.strip)
     end
```

If the uploaded file contains a mix of Windows and Unix encodings, presumably being due to copying from multiple places, Rails doesn't properly seperate each line of the file and sometimes returns two lines as one.

The application is hosted on a Linux box. Also, the file is copied from a Google docs spreadsheet column.

Are there any solutions for this problem?

---

Edit:

Hex code for lines that don't get seperated into new lines look like:

```
636f 6d0d 0a4e 6968
```

Comment: Remove `\r` by `gsub(/\r/,'')` and split by `\n`

Comment: Thanks @YevgeniyAnfilofyev I tried this file_data.read.gsub( /\r/, "" ).split("\n").each do |line|

but no luck same issue.

Comment: Well, in case you have lines without spaces, try this one `...read.split(/\s+/).each do..` without `gsub`

Comment: Thanks for the new approach,  but I am getting same issue. :( 

Maybe it is a problem with the files. need to go back to the drawing board :(

Comment: You should look into file with hex editor and find out what chars're used to separate lines...

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev I opened the file in a hex editor and the characters which are doing the new line are 0d 0a. These are same for both lines which get read as separate and lines which are considered same

Comment: You have to preprocess the file to normalize the line-endings, or you have to write your own code to handle line-ending variations. Ruby assumes a line-ending based on the OS it's running on, just like many other languages. It expects the file to be use consistent line-endings throughout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd go about this. First, to test some code:

```
SAMPLE_TEXT = [
  "now\ris\r\nthe\ntime\n",
  "for all good men\n"
]

def read_file(data)
  data.each do |li|                       
    [ *li.split(/[\r\n]+/) ].each do |l|  
      yield l                             
    end                                   
  end                                     
end

read_file(SAMPLE_TEXT) do |li|
  puts li                       
end
```

Which outputs:

```
now
is
the
time
for all good men
```

The magic occurs in `[ *li.split(/[\r\n]+/) ]`. Breaking it down:

- `li.split(/[\r\n]+/)` causes the line to be split on returns, new-lines and combinations of those. If a line has multiples the code will gobble empty lines, so if there's a chance you'll receive those you'll need a little more sophisticated pattern, `/[\r\n]{1,2}/` which, though untested, should work.
- `*li.split(/[\r\n]+/)` uses the "splat" operator `*` which says to explode the following array into its component elements. This is a convenient way to get an array when you're not sure whether you have a single element or an array being passed into a method.
- `[*li.split(/[\r\n]+/)]` takes the components returned and turns them back into a single array.

To modify the method to handle a file instead is easy:

```
def read_file(fname)
  File.foreach(fname) do |li|
    [ *li.split(/[\r\n]+/) ].each do |l|
      yield l
    end
  end
end
```

Call it almost the same way as in the previous example:

```
read_file('path/to/file') do |li|
  puts li                       
end
```

The reason you want to use [`foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) is it'll read line-by-line, which is a lot more memory efficient than slurping a file using [`read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-read) or [`readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-readlines), either of which read the entire file into memory at once. [`foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) is extremely fast also, so you don't take a speed-hit when using it. As a result there's little advantage to `read`-type methods, and good advantages to using `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

You are substituting `\n` with `\r\n`, which is problematic when parsing Windows files. Now `\r\n` becomes `\r\r\n`.

Better is to substitute to the Unix line ending format and then split on `\n`:

```
file_data.read.gsub( /\n/, "\r\n" ).split("\r\n").each do |line|
```

becomes:

```
file_data.read.gsub( /\r\n/, "\n" ).split("\n").each do |line|
```

Comment: Thanks. You're right about the bug. But I had tried this previous approach already and it didn't work. but I'll try it again just to be sure

Comment: No Luck :(. The same issue is happening. Around 4-5 lines out of a text file are being read together. In Sublime text in windows I see each line seperately

Comment: Could you post the lines that are causing you trouble?

Comment: I wish i could but the file is full of email addresses that I am not allowed to disclose :( Is there any other way to do it.?
If I create a test file from scratch the parsing works fine. 
But the data is copied from a google spreadsheet

Comment: Be careful using `read`. It loads the entire file into memory, which, with big files, will make your program process at a crawl.

Answer (score 0):

Try the built-in method:

```
File.readlines('foo').each do |line|
```

Or:

```
File.open('foo').read.gsub(/\r\n?/, "\n").each_line do |line|
```

Comment: Both solutions have scalability problems due to slurping the file if the file is larger than Ruby can handle.